# SharePoint Designer list workflow condition - If Current Item: Equals No

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have the above condition in a workflow and I'm trying to figure out what it actually means since no "Field from Source" from Data Source "Current Item" is actually specified. Anyone ?

Comment: Field might have been deleted. You can correct this by selecting a relevant list field that the if condition should be validating.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the field you were checking upon was deleted.

Comment: Possibly, seems odd though as the same condition is used in the Else clause so it would have been deleted twice